# Why is an openMP/MPI distributed process slower than in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, multiprocessing, openmp, distributed-computing, openmpi

I wrote a hybrid OpenMP/MPI program that basically distributes the iterations of a `for(){...}` loop to non-shared memory systems through MPI. Within one machine, I call openMP specifically with a static schedule.

My code abstractly looks like the following:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) collapse(2) nowait
for(j=1;j>-2;j-=2){
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        ...                    // nested loop code here
    }
}
```

I compared the running times of the exact same piece of code on MATLAB with a `parfor` loop and I get a consistently 30% slower running time with my `C` code.

I expect at least equal running times, if not faster for the `C` code.

I monitor running times through the shell function `time` like the following

`time matlab script.m`

`time mpirun -np 1 --bind-to none -x OMP_NUM_THREADS=32 ./script`

I am using openmp 3.1 with gcc 4.7.3 and openMPI v1.10.3

I call the program with `--bind-to none` option in  openMPI and `OMP_PROC_BIND=TRUE` for openMP

**Any ideas why does that happen?**

---

### EDIT

Assuming 32 threads, in MATLAB, the loop looks like this:

```
parfor k=1:nWorkers
    for j=[-1,1]
       for i=1:n
           ...                 % nested loop here
       end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop you paralellize is **`for(j=1;j>-2;j-=2)`**, which is only `j=1` and `j=-1`. Therefore you only get two threads doing `n` loops. I can imagine you are doing something else in MATLAB, but you did not provide any code, so I can't say anything about your MATLAB code.

Also you are combining MPI (with just one thread) with openMP, are you sure that is what you are looking for?

Comment: Isn't collapse(2) supposed to merge both loops into one? like in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482833/understanding-the-collapse-clause-in-openmp).
I set -np 1 to be able to compare with matlab in a shared-memory system.
In matlab I have the same loop but instead of for I have a parfor.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR; - best practices included below for both MATLAB and C-lang.

(Entering the HPC and distributed computing domains requires some new sort of self-discipline, as the toys get more and more complicated and the net-effects are not easily deconstructed to their respective root-causes if relying just on our previous purely [SERIAL] scheduling experience from common programming languages).

### Never use shell `time` to seriously measure / compare a performance:

the more once your distributed concurrent processes reach some high number of openMP threads / MPI processes, setting the divisor **`N`** in the [**Amdahl's Law** denominator](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3).

```
                                1
processSPEEDUP = _______________________________
                               ( 1 - SEQ_part )     <---- CONCURRENCY MAY HELP
                  SEQ_part +  _________________
                  ^^^                 N             <---- CONCURRENCY HARNESSED
                  |||
                  SEQ____________________________________ CONCURRENCY IMMUNE PART
```

Anticipations ought be realistic:

[image]

### Never expect a SPEEDUP-dinner to be as FREE
as an overhead-naive
formulation of [Amdahl's Law](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) may seemed to have promised

Never use shell time to seriously measure / compare a performance:

the more once your distributed concurrent processes reach some high number of openMP threads / MPI processes, setting the divisor **`N`** in the Amdahl's Law denominator.

```
                               1
processSPEEDUP = ___________________________________
                             ( 1 - SEQ_part )        <-- CONCURRENCY MAY HELP
                 SEQ_part + _________________ + CoST 
                 ^^^                 N          ^^^
                 |||                 ^          |||
                 |||                 |          |||        
                 |||                 +------------------ CONCURRENCY HARNESSED
                 |||                            |||
                 |||                            |||      A GAIN WITHOUT PAIN?
                 |||                            |||      
                 |||                            |||      NEVER, SORRY,
                 |||                            |||      COMMUNISM DOES NOT WORK,
                 |||                            |||      ALL GOT AT THE COST OF
                 |||                            +++----- COSTS-OF-ALL-OVERHEADS
                 |||                                     ++++++++++++++++++++++
                 |||                                     +N job SETUPs
                 |||                                     +N job DISTRIBUTIONs
                 |||                                     +N job COLLECT RESULTs
                 |||                                     +N job TERMINATIONs
                 |||
                 |||
                 SEQ____________________________________ CONCURRENCY IMMUNE PART
```

[For **more details** on the impacts from add-on costs-of-overheads, **may like to read this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46931460/3666197), or may jump straight into an interactive GUI-tool for a live, quantitative reality-based illustration on how small speedup any amount of CPU will bring on **"*expensively*" distributed jobs**, referenced in the trailer part of [**this post**, where **SPEEDUPs** are shown
 **WHY** they actually turn out to **become SLOWDOWNs, on any amount of `N`**
 Q.E.D.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46124635).

Plus there are some more details on actual constraints ( threading model related, hardware domain related, NUMA specific ), that altogether decide about the resulting scheduling and the achievable speed-up of the such declared flow of execution :

[image]

---

Independently from the details how a process may get accelerated by a distributed processing concurrency, the quality of measurement is discussed here.

---

### Processes in C shall always use :

any high resolution timer available in the system. As a fast mock-up example, one may:

```
#include <time.h>

struct timespec {
                 time_t tv_sec;  /* seconds */
                 long   tv_nsec; /* nanoseconds */
       };

timespec diff( timespec start, timespec end ) {
         timespec temp;
         if ( ( end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec ) <  0 ) {
               temp.tv_sec  = end.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec  - 1;
               temp.tv_nsec = end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec + 1000000000;
         } else {
               temp.tv_sec  = end.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec;
               temp.tv_nsec = end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
         }
         return temp;
       }

// /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
       struct timespec                           start_ts, end_ts, duration_ts;
       clock_gettime( CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID,  &start_ts );
//     clock_gettime( CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &start_ts );
//     clock_gettime( CLOCK_MONOTONIC,          &start_ts );
// ____MEASURED-SECTION_START____________________
                ...
                ..
                .
// ____MEASURED-SECTION_END______________________
       clock_gettime( CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID,  &end_ts );
//     clock_gettime( CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &end_ts );
//     clock_gettime( CLOCK_MONOTONIC,          &end_ts );
        // _____SECTION__________
        //         duration_ts = diff( start_ts, end_ts );
// \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/
```

---

### Processes in MATLAB shall always use `tic; ...; delta = toc;`

MathWorks Technical Article arguments quite clearly on this subject:

> In summary, use `tic` and `toc` to measure elapsed time in MATLAB, because the functions have the highest accuracy and most predictable behavior. The basic syntax is

```
tic;
    ... % … computation …
    ..
    .
toc;
```

> where the `tic` and `toc` lines are recognized by MATLAB for minimum overhead.