# Can a Parallel Processing Efficiency become > 1?

Tags: parallel-processing, hpc

I read about efficiency in parallel computing, but never got an clear idea about it, also I read about achieving efficiency **`>1`** and conclude that it's possible when it's a super linear.

Is that correct and possible?

If yes, then can anybody tell me how and provide an example for that?

Or, if it is not, then why?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup#Super-linear_speedup

Answer (score 0):

### Let's agree on a few terms first:

A set of processes may get scheduled for execution under several different strategies --

- **`[SERIAL]`** - i.e. execute one after another has finished, till all are done, or
- **`[PARALLEL]`** - i.e. all-start at once, all-execute at once, all-terminate at once

or

- in a "just"-**`[CONCURRENT]`** fashion - i.e. some start at once, as resources permit, others are scheduled for `[CONCURRENT]` execution whenever free or new resources permit. The processing gets finished progressively, but without any coordination, just as resources-mapping and priorities permit.

### Next,
let's define a measure, how to compare a processing efficiency, right?

Given an efficiency may be related to power-consumption or to processing-time, let's focus on processing-time, ok?

Gene Amdahl has elaborated domain of generic processing speedups, from which we will borrow here. The common issue in HPC / computer science education is that lecturers do not emphasise the real-world costs of organising the parallel-processing. For this reason, the overhead-naive ( original ) formulation of the Amdahl's Law ought be always used in an **overhead-strict** re-formulation, because otherwise any naive-form figures are in [parallel-computing](/questions/tagged/parallel-computing)
 just comparing apples to oranges.

On the other hand, once both the process-add-on-setup-overhead costs and process-termination-add-on-overhead costs are recorded into the scheme, the **overhead-strict speedup comparison starts to make sense** to speak about processing-time efficiency.

Having said this, there are cases, when processing-time efficiency can become **`> 1`**, while it is fair to say, that a professional due care has to be taken and that not all processing-types permit to gain any remarkable speedup on whatever large-scale pool of code-execution resources, right due to the obligation to pay and cover the add-on costs of the NUMA / distributed-processing overheads.

---

## May like to read further and experiment

- with an [**overhead-strict Amdahl Law re-formulation**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) [`[PARALLEL]`-processing  speedups GUI-**interactive-tool cited here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46124635)
- Being in Sweden, your must-read is the [Andreas Olofsson's personal story](https://www.parallella.org/2016/10/05/epiphany-v-a-1024-core-64-bit-risc-processor/) about his remarkable effort and experience with piloting parallel-hardware [**with many first-ever**-s on the way from Kickstarter to a DARPA-acquired **`[PARALLEL]`-hardware** know-how.](http://www.adapteva.com/andreas-blog/adapteva-status/)