# Best way to parallelize this Java code

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

How would I go about parallelizing this piece of code with the use of `Threads` in Java? It extracts all the contour from an image and creates a new image with only the image contour.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Contornos {

static int h, w;

static float debugTime;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        File fichImagen = new File("test.jpg");

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fichImagen);

        w = image.getWidth();
        h = image.getHeight();

        int[] inicial = new int[w * h];

        int[] resultadoR = new int[w * h];
        int[] resultadoG = new int[w * h];
        int[] resultadoB = new int[w * h];

        int[][] procesarR = new int[h][w];
        int[][] procesarG = new int[h][w];
        int[][] procesarB = new int[h][w];

        int[][] procesarBN = new int[h][w];

        int[][] binaria = new int[h][w];

        int[] resultado = new int[w * h];

        image.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, inicial, 0, w);

        for (int i = 0; i < w * h; i++) {
            Color c = new Color(inicial[i]);
            resultadoR[i] = c.getRed();
            resultadoG[i] = c.getGreen();
            resultadoB[i] = c.getBlue();
        }

        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                procesarR[i][j] = resultadoR[k];
                procesarG[i][j] = resultadoG[k];
                procesarB[i][j] = resultadoB[k];
                k++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {

                procesarBN[i][j] = (int) (0.2989 * procesarR[i][j] + 0.5870 * procesarG[i][j] + 0.1140 * procesarB[i][j]);

            }
        }


        binaria = extraerContornos(procesarBN);

        k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                resultado[k++] = binaria[i][j];
            }
        }

        image.setRGB(0, 0, w, h, resultado, 0, w);
        ImageIO.write(image, "JPG", new File("allJPG.jpg"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

}

static void debugStart() {
    debugTime = System.nanoTime();
}

static void debugEnd() {
    float elapsedTime = System.nanoTime()-debugTime;

    System.out.println( (elapsedTime/1000000) + " ms ");  
}

private static int[][] extraerContornos(int[][] matriz) {
    int modx, mody;

    int[][] sobelx = {{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};
    int[][] sobely = {{-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}};

    int[][] modg = new int[h][w];
    double[][] theta = new double[h][w];
    int[][] thetanor = new int[h][w];
    int[][] contorno = new int[h][w];

    int umbral = 10;
    int superan = 0, ncontorno = 0;
    double t;
    int signo;
    int uno, dos;

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == h - 1 || j == 0 || j == w - 1) {
                modg[i][j] = 0;
                theta[i][j] = 0.0;
                thetanor[i][j] = 0;
            } else {
                modx = 0;
                mody = 0;
                for (int k = -1; k <= 1; k++) {
                    for (int l = -1; l <= 1; l++) {
                        modx += matriz[i + k][j + l] * sobelx[k + 1][l + 1];
                        mody += matriz[i + k][j + l] * sobely[k + 1][l + 1];
                    }
                }
                modx = modx / 4;
                mody = mody / 4;

                modg[i][j] = (int) Math.sqrt(modx * modx + mody * mody);

                theta[i][j] = Math.atan2(mody, modx);
                thetanor[i][j] = (int) (theta[i][j] * 256.0 / (2.0 * Math.PI));
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < h - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < w - 1; j++) {
            contorno[i][j] = 0;
            if (modg[i][j] >= umbral) {
                superan++;
                t = Math.tan(theta[i][j]);
                if (t >= 0.0) {
                    signo = 1;
                } else {
                    signo = -1;
                }
                if (Math.abs(t) < 1.0) {
                    uno = interpolar(modg[i][j + 1], modg[i - signo][j + 1], t);
                    dos = interpolar(modg[i][j - 1], modg[i + signo][j - 1], t);
                } else {
                    t = 1 / t;
                    uno = interpolar(modg[i - 1][j], modg[i - 1][j + signo], t);
                    dos = interpolar(modg[i + 1][j], modg[i + 1][j - signo], t);
                }
                if (modg[i][j] > uno && modg[i][j] >= dos) {
                    ncontorno++;
                    contorno[i][j] = 255;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    debugEnd();

    return contorno;

}

private static int interpolar(int valor1, int valor2, double tangente) {
    return (int) (valor1 + (valor2 - valor1) * Math.abs(tangente));
}
}
```

I believe I can use Threads in the `extraerContornos` method (for the for loops), and `join()` them at the end to get the results, but that's just my guess.

Would that be a correct way to parallelize this? Any tips in general on how to know when and where you should start parallelizing any code?

Comment: `I believe I can use Threads ...` - Why do not try that?

Comment: I have tried using threads in the part I mentioned in the post without success. The image came out black (most likely due to a race condition). So I don't really know where to implement the threads exactly.

Comment: Look up concurrency in java.

Comment: If you suspect race conditions, then find out which array's elements may be accessed concurrently; then wrap these accesses with `synchronize()`. General tip for parallelization: Find out independent (by data access) calculations, and move these calculations into different threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Tips in general on how to know
when and where you should start parallelizing any code?

Well,
**never ever start parallelizing** any code, without having a quantitatively supported evidence, that it will improve system performance.

**NEVER EVER,**
even if any academicians or wannabe gurus tell you to do so.

First collect a fair amount of evidence, that it has **any** sense at all and how big will be a positive edge such code re-engineering will bring, over an original, pure-**`[SERIAL]`,** code-execution flow.

It is like in nature or like in business -- who will ever pay a single cent more for getting a same result?

Who will pay X-[man*hours] work at current salary rates for getting just the first 1.01x improvement in performance ( not speaking about wannabe-parallel-gangstas, who manage to deliver even worse than original performance ... because of un-seen before hidden costs of add-on overheads ) -- who will ever pay for this?

---

### How to start to analyse possible benefits v/s negative impacts?

First of all, try to understand the "mechanics", **how** can the layered, composite system -- consisting of [ O/S-kernel, programming language, user program ] -- orchestrate going forward using either a "just"-**`[CONCURRENT]`** or true-**`[PARALLEL]`** process-scheduling.

Without knowing this, one can never quantify the actual costs of the entry, and sometimes people even pay all such costs without ever realising, that the resulting processing-flow is yet never even at least a "just"-`[CONCURRENT]` processing ( if one forgets to understand a central "concurrency-preventing-by-exclusive-LOCK-ing" blocking of a python GIL-locking, which could well help mask some sorts of I/O-latencies, but never indeed any kind of improving of a CPU-bound processing-performance, yet all have to pay all those immense costs of spawning full-copies of the process execution-environment + python-internal-state -- all that for receiving nothing at the end. NOTHING. Yes, that bad may things go, if poor or missing knowledge preceded a naive attempt to "go parallelize" activism ).

Ok, once you feel comfortable in operating-system "mechanics" available for spawning threads and processes, you can guesstimate or better benchmark the costs of doing that -- to **start working quantitatively -- knowing how many [ns] one will have to pay** to spawn a first, second, ... thirtyninth child thread or separate O/S process, or what will be the add-on costs for using some higher-level language constructor, that fans-out a herd of threads/processes, distributes some amount of work and finally collects the heaps of results back to the original requestor ( using just the high-level syntax of `.map(...){...}`, `.foreach(...){...}` et al, which on their lower ends do all the dirty job just hidden from the sight of the user-programme designer ( not speaking about "just"-coders, who even do not try to spend any but zero efforts on a fully responsible understanding of the "mechanics" + "economy" of costs of their "just"-coded work ) ).

Without knowing the **actual costs** in `[ns]` ( technically not depicted for clarity and brevity [**in** <kbd>**Fig.1**</kbd>, **that are principally always present,** being detailed and discussed in the trailer sections](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) ), it makes almost no sense for anyone to try to read and to try to understand in its full depth and its code-design context [the **criticism** of the Amdahl's Law](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3)

### It is so easy to pay more than one will receive at the end ...

For more details on this risk, check [this and follow the link from the first paragraph, leading to a fully interactive GUI-simulator of the actual costs of overheads, once introduced into the costs/benefits formula.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46941164/julia-parallel-code-slower-than-sequential-code-are-there-alternatives-to-remo/46942638#46942638)

Back to your code:

Sobel-filter kernel introduces ( naive-)-thread-mapping non-local dependencies, better to start with a way simple section, where an absolute independence is straight visible:

May save all the repetitive `for(){...}`-constructor overheads and increase performance:

```
    for (     int i = 0; i < h; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < w; j++ ) {

            Color c = new Color( inicial[i * w + j] );

            procesarBN[i][j] = (int) ( 0.2989 * c.getRed()
                                     + 0.5870 * c.getGreen()
                                     + 0.1140 * c.getBlue()
                                       );
        }
    }
```

Instead of these `triple-for(){...}`-s:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < w * h; i++) {
        Color c = new Color(inicial[i]);
        resultadoR[i] = c.getRed();
        resultadoG[i] = c.getGreen();
        resultadoB[i] = c.getBlue();
    }

    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            procesarR[i][j] = resultadoR[k];
            procesarG[i][j] = resultadoG[k];
            procesarB[i][j] = resultadoB[k];
            k++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {

            procesarBN[i][j] = (int) (0.2989 * procesarR[i][j] + 0.5870 * procesarG[i][j] + 0.1140 * procesarB[i][j]);

        }
    }
```

### Effects?

In the **`[SERIAL]`**-part of the Amdahl's Law:

- **at net zero add-on costs**: improved / eliminated 2/3 of the `for(){...}`-constructor looping overhead costs
- **at net zero add-on costs**: improved / eliminated the `( 4 * h * w * 3 )`-**memIO** ( i.e. not paying ~ h * w * 1.320+ [us] each !!! )
- **at net zero add-on costs**: improved / eliminated the `( 4 * h * w * 3 * 4  )`-**memALLOCs**, again saving remarkable amount of resources both in `[TIME]` and `[SPACE]`, polynomially scaled domains of the complexity ZOO taxonomy.

and also may feel safe to run these in a **`[CONCURRENT]`** processing, as this pixel-value processing is principally independent here ( but not in the Sobel, not in the contour-detector algorithm ).

So, here,
any **`[CONCURRENT]`** or **`[PARALLEL]`** process-scheduling may help, if

- at **some non-zero** add-on cost, the processing gets harnessing multiple computing resources ( more than the **1 CPU-core**, that was operated in the original, pure-`[SERIAL]`, code-execution ), will have been safely pixel-grid mapped onto such ( available resources-supported ) thread-pool or other code-processing facility.

Yet,
any attempt to go non-**`[SERIAL]`** **makes sense if and only if** the lumpsum of all the process-allocation / deallocation et al add-on costs get at least justified by an increased amount of **`[CONCURRENT]`**-ly processed calculations.

### Paying more than receiving is definitely not a smart move...

So, benchmark, benchmark and benchmark, before deciding what may get positive effect on production code.

Always try to get improvements in the pure-**`[SERIAL]`** sections, as these have zero-add-on costs and yet may reduce the overall processing time.

Q.E.D. above.