# Trying to understand Amdahl's Law

Tags: math, computer-science, theory, computation-theory, parallelism-amdahl

I am trying to answer a school assignment but i am getting confused to what the question is trying to ask.

> A design optimization was applied to a computer system in order to increase the performance of a given
> execution mode by a factor of 10. The optimized mode is used 50% of the time, measured as a percentage
> of the execution time after the optimization has been applied.
>
> (a)
> What is the global speedup value that is achieved with this optimization?
> *Remind:*
> Amdahl’s law defines the global speedup as a function of the optimized fraction before the optimization is applied. As a consequence, the 50% ratio cannot be directly used to evaluate this
> speedup value.
>
> (b)
> What is the percentage of the original execution time that is affected by this optimization?
>
> (c)
> How much should such execution mode be optimized in order to achieve a global speedup of 5?
> Can a global speedup of 12 be achieved?
> And 11?

When trying to calculate answer A) i came to the answer 1.81 ( 20/11 )

T' = 0.5 * T + 0.5 * T / 10 = T / 2  +  ( 1 / 20 ) T = ( 11 / 20 ) * T

Speedup = T / T'  = T / ( ( 11 / 20 ) * T = 20 / 11 = 1.81

For me this answer makes sense but in the professor's solutions say otherwise:

> (a) 5.5
>
> (b) 91%
>
> (c)
> Yes it can with an optimization by a factor of 25 / 3.
> No, because the factor can’t be negative, so it is impossible.
> Also no, because ∞ optimization → impossible

I can't solve the other ones because I am confused with the first one.

Why is 5.5 the correct answer?

Comment: That being said, I think your problem is not in understanding but in carrying out the arithmetic. Maybe try a visual solution by drawing some boxes representing the computation times.

Comment: The math is wrong? In what way? Maybe i have a typo

Comment: I can't quite put my finger on it, but my solution is that now the system spends 1 time unit doing one task and 1 time unit doing a second task, where before the optimization the second task took 10 time units. So the speedup is (1+10)/(1+1) = 11/2 = 5.5.

Comment: I think your mistake is trying to express T' in terms of T while the given information actually leads to expressing T in terms of T': T = T'/2 + 10 T'/2 = 11/2 T', from which the solution follows immediately.

Comment: Oh i see!!  Your second comment made a lot of sense. I still can't figure out the second and the third question. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you draw some boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose a computer has two states A and B, and after whatever optimization, it spends `0 ≤ p ≤ 1` of its time in state A, and `q = 1 - p` of its time in state B. (So `p` is something like .5, or .27).

State A was sped up by a factor of  X.  State B was sped up by a factor of Y.

So before, it was spending time `p * X + q * Y` time that it can now do in `p + q = 1` unit of time.  So its speed up is `p * X + q * Y`.

Applying this to the problem you were given:
`p = q = .5`, `X=10`, `Y=1` (no speedup).
`10 * (.5) + 1 * (.5) = 5.5`

This easily generalizes.

Answer (score 0):

After optimization, time = x minutes optimized mode + x minutes other = 2x.

Before optimization, time = 10x minutes unoptimized mode + x minutes other = 11x.

Speedup = 11x/2x = 5.5

Answer (score 0):

I love Amdahl's [argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70635529/3666197), incl. "[improvers](https://web.archive.org/web/20220108144606/https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18374629/revisions)", so let's start from **facts**

I will not answer the assignment questions directly, yet will help you learn the know-why, which is to my deepest belief & decades of joy to experience working with the most skilled people the core of what education should promote in our knowledge

> *( introducing text, decomposed )*
>
> ```c
> A design optimization was applied to a COMPUTER SYSTEM ___ [Fig.1:A]
>                       in order
>                       to increase the performance
>                       of a given
>                            EXECUTION MODE_________________ [Fig.1:B]
>                       by a FACTOR
>                            of 10._________________________ [Fig.1:C]
> ```

Fig.1 :

```
BEFORE  
      +------------------------------------------------------------A: SYSTEM
      |  +----------------------------------------------------B    |
      |  |                                                    |    |
      |  |                                                    |    |
      |  |                                                    |    |
      |  +----------------------------------------------------+    |
      +--:----------------------------------------------------:----+
         :                                                    :
         :                                                    :
         :           C: FACTOR ~ 10 x_________________________/
         :          /
AFTER    :         /
      +--:--------/--A*
      |  +------B*   |
      |  | 10x  |    |
      |  | less |    |
      |  | time |    |
      |  +123456+    |
      +12+------+3456+

D:         in smarter, optimised  "EXECUTION MODE",
  the 50% was duration of the said EXECUTION MODE, whereas
      50% was duration of the original, not modified, part
```

> <sup>*( ... text continued, decomposed )*</sup>
>
> ```c
> The optimized mode is used 50% of the TIME,__________ [FACT Fig.1:D]
>                                       measured
>                                    as 
>                                     a percentage of the execution time
>                                 AFTER the optimization
>                                       has been applied.
> ```

---

> <sup>*( ... first question, decomposed )*</sup>
>
> ```c
>   (a) What is the global SPEEDUP value
>                                  that is achieved
>                                              with ( AFTER )
>                                              this optimization?
> ```
>
> <sub>*Remind: Amdahl’s law defines the global speedup as a function of the optimized fraction before the optimization is applied. As a consequence, the 50% ratio cannot be directly used to evaluate this speedup value.*</sub>

> <sup>*( ... second question )*</sup>
> (b) What is the percentage of the original execution time that is affected by this optimization?

```
full-A-duration ~  10 x duration-of-B* // == duration-of-B         as was BEFORE
                  + 1 x duration-of-B* // == duration-of-( A - B ) as is
                                       // == duration-of-( A*- B*)    the same
( ref: FACT [Fig.1:D] )
```

Since here,
the [classics](https://web.archive.org/web/20120831195729/www.johngustafson.net/pubs/pub13/amdahl.htm) apply

> --- just do not forget what to compare to what ( and keep in mind, that one and the very same word may bear quite different actual meanings - just compare the original paper with Dr. Gene M. AMDAHL's ( IBM Research ) argument with the E. BARSIS' ( Sandia Natl. Lab.s ) "*scaled **speedup***" and the later John L. GUSTAFSON's presented ( ***reversed** optics* or "***opposite** point of view*" ) speedup - all use the same word S-P-E-E-D-U-P, yet their respective definitions differ ( and a lot )
> You might like to read the very original, authentic, Dr. Gene M. AMDAHL's paper, to see the actual argument wording as was [archived in FAQs](https://web.archive.org/web/20201031200446/http://wotug.org/parallel/internet/usenet/comp.parallel/FAQ/), the file is in section **"FAQ part 20: IBM and Amdahl"**, where the paper is on the very bottom of that text ). Alan KARP's price ( and also its winners ) is also a delightful part of this part of the computing history :o)

> <sup>*( ... third, fourth and fifth questions )*</sup>
> (c) How much should such EXECUTION MODE <sup>*(improving just the block `B`-to-`B*` )*</sup> be optimized in order to achieve a global speedup of 5?
> Can a global speedup
>  <sub>*here not restricted to touch only `B`, so can be smart in improving `A`-to-`A*` :P professor will either accept and warmly appreciate your skills and insightful argumentation on doing this, or punish you to dare use crystal-clear logic of the task to the limits the text was not prohibiting us from doing so ;) -- `[ SAFETY WARNING ]` best not to use this skilled strategy on auto-grader(s) or Artificial-"Intelligence"-powered grading Bots... for obvious reasons these rigid, pre-wired or LSqE-penalised algorithms will hardly award you any extra points for innovative thinking, as thinking is "not included" there, while batteries might 've been, might've been not? )*</sub>
> of 12 be achieved?
> And 11?